# Hauppauge WinTV-HVR-2250 tuner firmware to work in 12.04 Mythubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, mythbuntu, tv-tuner, firmware, hvr-2250

I have a HTPC running 10.10 and am trying to get the firmware.  I have tried the downloads from [www.kernellabs.com](http://www.kernellabs.com) and instructions from http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hauppauge_WinTV-HVR-2200 for the saa1764 firmware, but I think these may not apply to the 3.2.0-24 kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's a lot easier than compiling it, here's the result:

The firmware did not make the upgrade.  A new version has to be installed.

LowSky, long term supporter of this driver and Mythtv provides the download and instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11205874&postcount=425).  He says he will update if there is a change!

Thanks to [crbnrod](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=993708) on [mythbuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=301) for the [answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12049307#post12049307).